# Android- How to get the uri of a photo taken

Tags: android, uri, android-bitmap, onactivityresult, android-image-capture

I am trying to get the URI of a photo taken with the phone. I am trying to convert the data passed to "onActivityResult" to a URI, then convert this URI to a string to store in my database. This method does work with videos, so how can this be achieved with a photo? I get a null pointer exception when I try to convert the data to URI. Should I use a different function to convert the photo data to a URI? My code is as follows:

Button intent to start video recorder:

```
recordVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startVideoFunction = new Intent();
            startVideoFunction.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(startVideoFunction, REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO);
        }
    });
```

Button intent to start photo capture:

```
takePhotosButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startPhotoFunction = new Intent();
            startPhotoFunction.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(startPhotoFunction, REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);
        }
    });
```

onActivityResult method:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO:

                videoUri = data.getData();

                String videoPath = videoUri.toString();
                videoDB.addVideoRow(videoPath);

                //displayVideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                //displayVideo.start();
                break;

        case  REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO:

            photoUri = data.getData();

            String photoPath = photoUri.toString();
            videoDB.addPhotoRow(photoPath);
            break;
        }
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
    //prevent crash when returning with Null data to mainactivity.
    }

}
```

*UPDATED onActivityResult*:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
 data) {
   // try {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_VIDEO:

                videoUri = data.getData();

                String videoPath = videoUri.toString();
                videoDB.addVideoRow(videoPath);

                //displayVideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);
                //displayVideo.start();
                break;

        case  REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO:

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);

            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

            String photoPath = finalFile.toString();


            videoDB.addPhotoRow(photoPath);

            break;
        }
    //}catch (NullPointerException e){
    //prevent crash when returning with Null data to mainactivity.
    //}

}


public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Uri from Image: Convert the Bitmap to Uri using below mentioned code. You can always change the Bitmap compression format to PNG but then avoid using the line .compress as it will be of no use. PNG don't get compressed.

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes); // Used for compression rate of the Image : 100 means no compression
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "xyz", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

To get the Absolute Path from Uri use this method

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int id_uri = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(id_uri); 
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong way. Now you will save only a thumbnail of the image taken and save that to file. While the orriginal full image is already in a file on the file system.

Tell the camera app with the intent where to store the image to be taken. Use a putExtra for EXTRA_OUTPUT.

Comment: Hi greenapps. I was looking this up and came across putExtra EXTRA_OUTPUT. I believe this just adds the Uri of the photo to the intent sent to onActivityResult, which would solve the problem. However, I do not know how to add the Uri with putExtra, would you mind showing how to do it?

Comment: Just google for examples. There are hundreds on this site. No the uri will not be available as parameter of onActivity result. You should 'remember' the used uri.

Comment: I have but I'm still struggling to adapt these examples to my code. Do I not need the actual file to add the Uri to the intent?

Comment: No. You only need a full file path to a file. The file does not have to exists yet. In many examples you can see them creating an empty file before calling the intent but this is not needed and wrong.

Comment: But I do need the Uri of the file of the photo just taken, in order to add it to the intent? I don't see how you can add the Uri of the file when it doesn't exist.

Comment: No. You choose a filename. You choose a directory. Now you have your full path to a file that does not exist. (The directory has to exist though). Now make a File object for it. And then an Uri with Uri.fromFile(fileobject);